# Shell Script: Get newest file (of an extension) from a directory

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I want to get newest file in a directory. I am using 
[BashFAQ/099](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099) as reference.
My Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function newest_file() {
    local file_ext="$2"
    local files=("$1"/*."${file_ext}")
    local newest="${files[@]:0:1}"
    for f in "${files[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$f" -nt "$newest" ]]; then
            newest="$f"
        fi
    done
    echo "$newest"
}

file_path
newest_file "${1:-$HOME/Downloads}" "${2:-*}"
```

Output:

```
➜  bash func_get_new_file.sh $HOME/reports txt 
/home/ashwin/reports/test4.txt
➜  bash func_get_new_file.sh $HOME/reports    
newest_file:2: no matches found: /home/ashwin/reports/*.*
```

1. I get error when file extension is *. I want to understand why *.* does not work.
2. I also want to understand the (..) syntax used for creating array of files in directory, i.e. files=("$1"/*.${file_ext}) in my code above.

---

As suggested by @Cyrus, updating code as per [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

---

On futher debug and reading other posts, I figured that passing asterisk as parameter is troublesome. I am updating my code to check any special characters being passed in $2 as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

newest_file() {
    local file_ext="$2"
    if [[ ! "${file_ext}" =~ ^[.a-zA-Z0-9]*$ ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: file extension can have "." or alphanumberic characters. Don't provide any ext if all files should be checked"
        return 1
    fi
    [[ -z "${file_ext}" ]] && local files=("$1"/*) || local files=("$1"/*.${file_ext})
    local newest="${files[@]:0:1}"
    for f in "${files[@]}"; do
        if [[ $f -nt $newest ]]; then
            newest="$f"
        fi
    done
    echo "$newest"
}

newest_file "${1:-$HOME/Downloads}" "${2}"
```

Unless anyone can provide a simple solution to passing asterisk, I will go with the above solution.

Comment: Why do you use bash tag?

Comment: @Cyrus, I expect script to work for both zsh and bash.

Comment: Replace `/bin/zsh` with `/bin/bash` and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: a globing issue…